# Laravel 5: Get attribute from Command

Tags: php, command, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks

I'm working with Commands and the Scheduler but there is something that I can't get and is the argument/option of the command.

**Controller**

```
public function findUsers($id)
{
    Artisan::queue('users:find', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
    'App\Console\Commands\FindUsers',
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();

    $schedule->command('users:find')->cron('* * * * *');
}
```

**Command**

```
    <?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use App\Connection;

class FindUsers extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'users:find';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Find users every minute';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        var_dump($this->argument('id'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [
            ['example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null],
        ];
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is this one:

```
The "id" argument does not exist.
```

Do you have any idea about how to get it?

Comment: If i found the solution I should to remove the question or better leave it in an answer?

Comment: Answer the question so that the answer is there for future generations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

All the structure is fine and just you need to set the name of the attribute in the array inside this function:

```
/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['id', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'],
    ];
}
```

As you can see I replaced the 'example' for 'id' so now I can catch the **id**
attribute.